# Swift 3 mode has been deprecated

Tags: xcode, xcode10.1

In Xcode 10.1 whenever I build my app I get the warning

> Swift 3 mode has been deprecated and will be removed in a later
>   version of Xcode. Please migrate "My Appp" to Swift 4.2 using  "Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…" in the Edit menu. (in target 'My App')

How can I suppress the warning?

I tried to convert but conversion fails and besides that my app depends on some Pods / libraries that I can not convert any way.

Is there a way to stop seeing the warning?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there's no way to remove this. You'll need to manually update your Pods / libraries to Swift 4.x or wait until someone does the job for you. Otherwise, you won't be able to build your project with a newer Xcode version at some point in the future.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes:

> Xcode 10 is the last release that will support Swift 3. Migrate your projects from Swift 3 code to Swift 4.2 syntax by opening the project and choosing Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax… (43101816)

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you where did you get this knowledge from?

Comment: It is stated in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes. Xcode 10 is the latest major version to support Swift 3. Xcode 11 won't even let you build with warnings, so you must update your Pods/libraries to newer versions.

Comment: Thank you, but I was asking about "there's no way to remove this" part of your statement. I understand that migration is needed just don't want to see the warning every day.

Comment: That warning comes from the project configuration itself, you can't remove it unless you want to silent all warnings. It'd be more productive for you to start migrating your dependencies. Good luck

Comment: That's all fine and good, but I've done that and the warning still doesn't go away.  I'm talking about a Cocoapod dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Download Xcode 10.1 to be able to compile your code with Swift 3 or Pod decencies:

```
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode
```